# $ y' + \tan(x)\,y = \cos^2(x)$, $y(0) = C$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $$ y' + \tan(x)\,y = \cos^2(x),\quad y(0) = C$$ For what values of C does the solution remain bounded for all values of x?

I tried solve this problem by considering this equation as a linear equation, and solve its homogeneous solution. But I don't know how to do it. Could you please help me to do this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Integrating factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Integrating factor:

$$ \text{Integrating factor} = e^{\int\tan x}= e^{\ln |secx|}= secx$$

Multiply through by integrating factor:
$$\text{sec}x \frac{dy}{dx} + y\tan x\ \text{sec}x =\cos x$$

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(y\text{sec}x)= \int \cos x \ dx$$

$$y \text{sec}x = \sin x + G$$

where $G$ is a constant

$$ y = \sin x \cos x + G\cos x$$
Using the boundary condition:

$$y = \sin x \cos x + C\cos x $$

Answer (score 0):

The integrating factor is $\sec x$. Then
$$\eqalign {y' + \tan x\cdot y &= \cos^2 x\cr
\sec x \cdot y' + \sec x\tan x\cdot y &= \sec x \cos^2 x = \cos x\cr
{d\over dx} [y \sec x] &= \cos x\cr
y\sec x &= +\sin x + C\cr
y &= +\sin x \cos x + C \cos x\cr
}$$

Comment: Oh, yeah, stupid $-$ signs ... Fixed.